# How I can compare two images using Python to say if they are similar?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I´m working on a project in which I need to compare two images and to say if they are similar, I'm using Python and OpenCV. Somebody know how I can do it?

Comment: How do you mean, similar?   I would start by converting to grayscale, then using the contrast levels to resize one image to correspond with the other.  This is not a simple task.

Comment: If you mean pixel-by-pixel comparison, then you might consider Python Wand, which is based upon ImageMagick. ImageMagick comes with Linux and can be installed on Windows or Mac OSX

Answer (score 1):

I've came across a project that required me to compare to images to see if they are similar. I will recommend this Python Lib. [Imagehash](https://pypi.org/project/ImageHash/) Go through the documentation to understand how it works.

Here is a sample Code:

```
from PIL import Image
import imagehash
img0 = imagehash.average_hash(Image.open('img1.jpg')) 
img1 = imagehash.average_hash(Image.open('img2.jpeg')) 
cutoff = 5

if img0 - img1 < cutoff:
  print('images are similar')
else:
  print('images are not similar')
```

requirements:

```
pip install ImageHash
pip install pillow
```